# Cannot link Arduino project to include Simulink Code

Tags: arduino, simulink, avr-gcc

At work, I recently took training on MATLAB/Simulink, including the Simulink Coder that can generate C code for embedded applications. I wanted to try my hand at it, so I bought an Arduino, and dove in. I am able to write simple sketches with no problem, but have been hitting a brick wall when trying to integrate the code generated by Simulink.

I initially used the Arduino IDE, then Eclipse with the Arduino plug-in, and finally Xcode with the embedXcode templates. (My work machine with Simulink is a PC, but I'm not allowed to install "unauthorized software", so I did the rest on my home Mac.) All three use the same avr-gcc compiler.

All three had the same point of failure: "Undefined Reference" errors on the generated function calls. I believe this to be a linker issue rather than basic syntax or header inclusion, as the Eclipse and Xcode code-completion are working OK, and if I change the call signature in any way, the error changes. I can make references to the data structures OK.

As far as I can tell, the default makefiles are set up to compile and link any files within the folder. A "mass_model2.o" file is being created, at least with Xcode. Finally, if I manually write a separate "myFunction.c" and "MyFunction.h" file with a simple function call, this does compile and run on the device as expected.

In desparation, I copied the entire contents of the generated ".c" file, and pasted them in the main sketch file after my `setup()` and `loop()` functions, keeping the same ".h" references, and removed the ".c" file from the project. This actually did compile and run! However, I should not have to touch the generated code in order to use it.

What do I need to do to get this to compile and link properly?

The Simulink code is quite verbose, so here are the key parts:

mass_model2.h excerpts:

```
#include "rtwtypes.h"
#include "mass_model2_types.h"

/* External inputs (root inport signals with auto storage) */
typedef struct {
  int16_T PotPos;                      /* '<Root>/PotPos' */
} ExternalInputs_mass_model2;

/* External outputs (root outports fed by signals with auto storage) */
typedef struct {
  int16_T ServoCmd;                    /* '<Root>/ServoCmd' */
} ExternalOutputs_mass_model2;

/* External inputs (root inport signals with auto storage) */
extern ExternalInputs_mass_model2 mass_model2_U;

/* External outputs (root outports fed by signals with auto storage) */
extern ExternalOutputs_mass_model2 mass_model2_Y;

/* Model entry point functions */
extern void mass_model2_initialize(void);
extern void mass_model2_step(void);
```

mass_model2.c excerpts:

```
#include "mass_model2.h"
#include "mass_model2_private.h"

/* External inputs (root inport signals with auto storage) */
ExternalInputs_mass_model2 mass_model2_U;

/* External outputs (root outports fed by signals with auto storage) */
ExternalOutputs_mass_model2 mass_model2_Y;

/* Model step function */
void mass_model2_step(void)
{
    // lots of generated code here
}

/* Model initialize function */
void mass_model2_initialize(void)
{
    // generated code here
}
```

The other referenced headers, "rtwtypes.h" and "mass_model2_private.h" define specific types that are used by the generated code, like `int16_T`. These files are included in the project, and I do not receive any errors associated with them.

In my sketch file, the `setup()` function calls `mass_model2_initialize()`. `loop()` reads my input (a potentiometer), sets the value in `mass_model2_U.PotPos`, and calls `mass_model2_step()`. It then gets `mass_model2_Y.ServoCmd` and writes the value to a servo for output, and finally has a `delay()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this download, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24675, with Simulink, Simulink Coder and Embedded Coder. Make sure you have the correct version numbers of each tool.

Comment: It looks like I should be using this version, since I am using R2012a: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35639. I'm giving this an upvote since it *should* work, although I am unable to install it at this time. (I've sumbitted a question to Mathworks on that page...) Information I had seen about the direct support indicatied that I/O support was limited and did not include Servo drive; this version appears to.

Answer (score 0):

The `#include "Arduino.h"` statement is required on the main sketch.